# Installing Kinect sdk 1.8 in Linux

Tags: linux, kinect, kinect-sdk, wine, xbox

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHyXf.png)
I have been trying to install Kinect sdk 1.8 in Linux OS with wine, but unable to complete the setup successfully.Below is the log file

[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:46]: Burn v3.6.2221.0, path: Z:\home\ashok\Downloads\KinectSDK-v1.8-Setup.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{2721075D-D4E6-40FB-801C-A6D060375474} {93F050BC-2A42-46FA-88D1-2EF39283F6AE} 40'
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:46]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value '(null)'
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:46]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\users\ashok\Temp\Setup_20160428142646.log'
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:46]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'Z:\home\ashok\Downloads\KinectSDK-v1.8-Setup.exe'
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:47]: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Detect 12 packages
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Setting string variable 'Netfx4ClientVersion' to value '4.0.30319'
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\Runtimes\x64'
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Setting string variable 'Netfx4x64ClientVersion' to value '4.0.30319'
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\Runtimes\x86'
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x64'
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Setting string variable 'VCRedistx86Installed' to value '1'
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Condition 'Netfx4ClientVersion AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx4x64ClientVersion)' evaluates to true.
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Detected package: Netfx4Client, state: Present, cached: No
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Condition 'VCRTx86Installed OR VCRedistx86Installed' evaluates to true.
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Detected package: VCRTx86, state: Present, cached: Yes
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Condition 'VCRTx64Installed OR VCRedistx64Installed' evaluates to false.
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Detected package: VCRTx64, state: Absent, cached: No
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Detected package: SpeechRTx86, state: Present, cached: No
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Detected package: SpeechRTx64, state: Absent, cached: No
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Detected package: enUSLangPack, state: Present, cached: No
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Detected package: x64Drivers, state: Absent, cached: No
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Detected related package: {143B3B42-9393-456F-BC9A-7BAED0AECF03}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.8.0.595, operation: MajorUpgrade
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Detected package: x64Runtime, state: Absent, cached: No
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Detected related package: {E7BBAF44-5039-44E3-A6E4-238FC671C705}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.8.0.595, operation: MajorUpgrade
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Detected package: x64SDK, state: Absent, cached: No
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Detected package: x86Drivers, state: Absent, cached: Yes
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Detected package: x86Runtime, state: Present, cached: Yes
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Detected package: x86SDK, state: Present, cached: Yes
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:52]: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Plan 12 packages, action: Install
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Planned package: Netfx4Client, state: Present, default requested: Present, ux requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Planned package: VCRTx86, state: Present, default requested: Present, ux requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Planned package: VCRTx64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ux requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Unregister
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Planned package: SpeechRTx86, state: Present, default requested: Present, ux requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Planned package: SpeechRTx64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ux requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Unregister
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Planned package: enUSLangPack, state: Present, default requested: Present, ux requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Planned package: x64Drivers, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ux requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Unregister
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Planned package: x64Runtime, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ux requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Unregister
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Planned package: x64SDK, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ux requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Unregister
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Condition 'NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_x86Drivers' to value 'C:\users\ashok\Temp\Setup_20160428142646_0_x86Drivers.log'
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_x86Drivers' to value 'C:\users\ashok\Temp\Setup_20160428142646_0_x86Drivers_rollback.log'
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Planned package: x86Drivers, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ux requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Condition 'NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Planned package: x86Runtime, state: Present, default requested: Present, ux requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Condition 'NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Planned package: x86SDK, state: Present, default requested: Present, ux requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Apply begin
[0028:0029][2016-04-28T14:26:59]: Caching executable from: 'Z:\home\ashok\Downloads\KinectSDK-v1.8-Setup.exe' to: 'C:\users\Public\Application Data\Package Cache{5f9eeaf3-984f-46b4-84f9-e8e1d5b255a8}\KinectSDK-v1.8-Setup.exe'
[0028:0029][2016-04-28T14:27:10]: Registering bundle dependency key: {5f9eeaf3-984f-46b4-84f9-e8e1d5b255a8}, version 1.8.0.595
[0028:0029][2016-04-28T14:27:11]: Applying package: x86Drivers, action: Install, path: C:\users\Public\Application Data\Package Cache{08E1AA2D-125D-4E80-AA43-C7B6D2CF9668}v1.8.0.595\KinectDrivers-v1.8-x86.WHQL.msi, arguments: '(null)'
[0028:0029][2016-04-28T14:27:12]: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[0028:0029][2016-04-28T14:27:12]: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:27:12]: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:27:12]: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:27:12]: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute apply.
[0028:0029][2016-04-28T14:27:12]: Removing bundle dependency key: {5f9eeaf3-984f-46b4-84f9-e8e1d5b255a8}
[0028:0029][2016-04-28T14:27:12]: Removing cached bundle: {5f9eeaf3-984f-46b4-84f9-e8e1d5b255a8}, from path: C:\users\Public\Application Data\Package Cache{5f9eeaf3-984f-46b4-84f9-e8e1d5b255a8}\
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:27:12]: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643 restart: No
[003F:0040][2016-04-28T14:27:47]: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0

Comment: Good luck, but I do not think installing MS Kinect SDK on Linux will ever work... Should be better to use some open source alternative, such as [OpenKinect](https://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page) or some other project

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your response, Openkinect, the code is  c++, which is not supported by unity(c#) hence will not be able to add GUI features